# How can I know client send FIN package in socket?

Tags: java, sockets

In client, when call `clent.close()`, it will send a FIN packet to try to end the connection. Are there any API for server side to know there comes a FIN packet to close the connection in server side? If not, why? What's the best pratice to close connection in both side?

Client code:

```
    String host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    int port = 8899;
    Socket client = new Socket(host, port);
    String data = "Hello world";
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(data);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    client.close();
```

A example can be seen [here](https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/de546ac2b4ca).

Comment: **PACKET** (not *package*). And that happens at a lower level of the protocol stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the peer receives a FIN:

- `read()` will return -1
- `readLine()` will return null
- `readXXX()` will throw `EOFException` for any other X.

What *won't* happen:

- `Socket.isClosed()` won't magically become true
- `Socket.isConnected()` won't magically become false.

Answer (score 0):

When the server receives a FIN, it will treat this as the end-of-stream condition.

In other words, every time you call `read` on the socket's InputStream, it will return -1 instead of reading any data - the same as if you were reading from a file and you got to the end of the file.

Comment: You will get -1, not 'zero bytes'. Zero bytes is only possible on (i) a non-blocking socket channel or (ii) an input stream if you supply a zero-length buffer or a zero `length` parameter, and does not indicate end of stream in either case.